# How to use label with picins package?

Tags: picins

In the manual it is said to use \label command inside \piccaption command but i don't understand how ?

I typed :
\piccaption{Caption text}{\label{test}}
but not working obviously.

Comment: As always here you are much more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal example that others can just copy and test as is.

Comment: Use `\piccaption{Caption text\label{test}}`.  `\label` is invisible after all.

Comment: thanks, that's what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

The `\label` should form part of the caption, so use

```
\piccaption{Caption text\label{test}}
```